# C++ When does it make sense to pass a const struct parameter by value vs. reference?

Tags: c++, parameters, reference, constants

I've seen a similar question to this, but i'd like some clarification...

Assuming a basic C++ class:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    struct SomeData
    {
        std::wstring name;
        std::vector<int> someValues;
    };

    void DoSomething(const SomeData data);
}
```

I understand that `data` will be passed as `const` to `DoSomething` and that is ok since `data` will not be modified in any way by the function...but I am used to seeing `&` specified with `const` parameters to ensure that they are passed by reference, e.g.

```
void DoSomething(const SomeData& data);
```

That seems more efficient to me. If we omit the `&`, then isn't `data` being passed by value to `DoSomething`? I'm not sure why it would ever be preferable to pass a `const` parameter by value when you can pass by reference and avoid the copy occurring?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass by value/reference and const-correctness are two different concepts. But used together.

**Pass by Value**

```
 void DoSomething (SomeData data);
```

Pass by value is used when it is less costly to copy and do not want to keep references to foreign objects. This function could (if it is inside a class) keep a pointer to this in some case and have its own copy.

**Pass by reference**

```
void DoSomething (SomeData& data);
```

Always use pass by reference if you know this might cause a performance loss copying the struct. This function could (if it is inside a class) keep a pointer to this in some case and pointing to a foreign object. Keeping pointers to foreign objects mean you should aware of its life-time and when this foreign object goes out of bound. More importantly changes to foreign object appears to your pointer.

**const correctness**

```
void DoSomething (const SomeData data);  // const for local copy
void DoSomething (const SomeData& data); //  const for callers object
```

Adding `const`to pass by value or reference means this function does not change it. But not having or having `&` decides which object you are trying to add safety of modifying. `const` is a very helpful tool in C++ in terms of Documenting APIs, provide compile time safety, allow more compiler optimizations.

[Read](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness) this article.

Comment: There is, of course, the problem of working out if creating a copy to pass by value is more or less costly than passing by reference.   For simple cases, it might be sufficient to use a rule of thumb based on size in memory of the object and its members, and of references, but those sizes are implementation-defined (i.e. can vary, albeit in a constrained way, between compilers) so the rules of thumb don't always work well. The rules of thumb also break down if constructors or destructors of objects behave differently, and increase or decrease cost of copying.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest problem with `void DoSomething(const SomeData data)` is that it conflates interface and implementation. From the caller's point of view, the `const` doesn't change anything; the function receives a copy anyway, and the original object is not modified. What the implementation does or does not with its own, function-internal copy should not bother the caller and should thus not be expressed in the interface.

The `const` does make the implementation more const-correct if the copy is not changed, but leaking implementation details into the interface is a high price to pay. I recommend not using `void DoSomething(const SomeData data)`.

As always, performance gains or losses should not be overestimated here. It's more about semantics and conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a `const` value is mostly informational for the caller, it shows intent. This is important to make code easy to read, understand and maintain.

It might also be possible for the compiler to add some extra optimizations if it knows that the function doesn't modify its argument. For example it might cause the compiler to not perform a copy at all.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
void DoSomething(const SomeData data);
```

is a bit unusual, because while it does not change anything for the caller (who can pass a const or non-const value), it restricts what the function can do internally.  There's not a lot of value in that, and it's not commonly done.

Passing by reference (const or not) is more efficient if the value is expensive to copy, including if it is larger than approximately two pointers on the target platform.  In other words, if `SomeData` were a struct containing two integers it would probably be more efficient to pass it by value.  But if it contains a `std::map` or some larger data, better pass it by reference.

An exception to this is if the function is going to copy the value anyway, then it is better to take it by value, because the value might be "moved" instead of copied if the caller allows it.